# Meteor build error : EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, node-gyp

I would like build my Meteor 1.4 app on Ubuntu 16.04 but i've this error :

> EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'

I run `sudo meteor build ../build`

I've test to remove ~/.node-gyp but no result.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This must be a permission issue. Please use chown command to change permissions to the directory to yourself and then try running the build again.

Try deleting the build folder in the .meteor/local link in this link
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/893

Comment: I've try this but no result : sudo chown -R $USERNAME /home/stephane

Comment: is this the command you are running ..............................."meteor build /path/to/build --architecture os.linux.x86_64". Also please see this link https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/893